# Grab text from the DOM using jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I wan to get the content within the < p > tag using jQuery. So I can have a Java variable with each players name. The jquery code sets playerN1 as a blank string instead of the players name. I was wondering why the text() was not grabbing the players name (whats within the < p > tags)?

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="match1">
  <div id="m1.p1" class="col3 first last bracket_player1">
    <p class="name">Player1 Name</p>
  </div>
  <div id="m1.p2" class="col3 first last bracket_player2">
    <p class="name">Player2 Name</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="match2">
  <div id="m2.p1" class="col3 first last bracket_player1">
    <p class="name">Player1 Name</p>
  </div>
  <div id="m2.p2" class="col3 first last bracket_player2">
    <p class="name">Player2 Name</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
// The jQuery
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
   var match = "m" + i;
   var elementID = "#"+match+".p1 "+"p";
   var playerN1 = $(elementID).text();
   console.log(elementID);
   console.log(playerN1);
}
```

Comment: You can't have a `.` in an ID.

Comment: @Mathletics: The `.` is a valid ID character, but you need to escape it in the selector. EDIT: As show in [@Rocket's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10181194/1106925).

Comment: @Mathletics: Technically, you can: http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022  I wouldn't suggest it, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the `.` in the ID.  `#m1.p1` is interpreted as `ID=m1 AND class=p1`.  You need to either escape the `.` ([with 2 `\`s](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F)).

```
var elementID = "#"+match+"\\.p1 "+"p";
```

Or use the [`[id=""]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
var elementID = "[id='"+match+".p1'] "+"p";
```

Comment: Yeah I was worried that might cause an issue. Thanks for sending the link to the ID selector. This is my first time using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you just grabbing them like this:

```
$('p.name').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});​
```

Comment: I need to keep tract of the matches as well which is why I couldn't just grab by .name thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `html()` instead of `text()` but I have a feeling the problem is with the `.` in the ID. I am not certain that is a valid character for an ID.

Answer (score 2):

To grab the value of each element with the class 'name' you would just loop through them:

```
$('.name').each(function(){
    var thisPlayer = this.text();
    console.log(thisPlayer);
});
```